# Algorithmic complexity of the 9 coin balancing puzzle?

Tags: time-complexity

The problem: you have `3^x` coins, one of which is heavier than the others. You have to use a set of balancing scales to determine which coin that is. The catch is that you're only allowed `x` weighings using the scale.

Eg.

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
       ^ 

Heavier coin is at index 2.
```

This doesn't work particularly well as a programming challenge because you could just traverse the array looking for the 1, ie. O(n). The correct answer is to split the coins into three groups, and weigh the first two. This allows you to determine which of the three groups contains the coin. Recursively weigh *that* group and so forth, until you're left with only a single coin. (Weighing can be emulated by taking the sum of the sublist).

I've been trying to figure out what the complexity of this algorithm would be. At first I thought it's O(log n) because you exclude parts of the dataset to converge on the answer, kind of like binary search. But you have to traverse each group to determine its weight, which would be O(n).

[Here is a reasonable example of the algorithm in C++](https://github.com/wellington-compsci/whiteboard/blob/master/2015-09-10/find-the-heavy-coin/solution.cpp). Please note that my C++ is poor at best, so try to focus on the logic more so than the code itself.

Having gone through a few scenarios by hand (with 9 and 27 coins), I feel like it's effectively an O(n) algorithm. How should I be stepping through this mathematically to be sure? I haven't done proofs yet.

Comment: It's N*log(N). log(N) is iteration count and N is a sum of the subsets for each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime works out to O(N), where N is the number of coins. To see why, note that each “phase” of the algorithm does a linear amount of work comparing the first and second third of the remaining coins against one another, then recursively repeats this process on one third of the remaining elements. That gives the recurrence relation

> T(N) = T(N / 3) + O(N),

which solves to O(N) by the Master Theorem. Intuitively, the work done per phase decays geometrically, so the total work done is some constant multiple of the work done in the initial phase.

While it is true that there are O(log N) phases and each does O(N) work, the bound of O(N log N) is not tight because the work done per phase decays so rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

It's N*log(N). log(N) is iteration count and N is a sum of the subsets for each iteration.